# Docker Containers failing to connect to each other - connection refused

Tags: typescript, mongodb, docker, graphql, nats.io

I have a simple application orchestrated by Docker Compose. It consists of a simple frontend (built using NextJS), a GraphQL API (built with NestJS), and a microservice (built with NestJS).

The architecture is as follows:

1. The frontend speaks directly to the GraphQL service.
2. The GraphQL service communicates to the microservice via a NATS server that acts as a message broker.
3. The microservice communicates directly with a MongoDB instance via the NodeJS driver library.

When I run everything locally, it all connects perfectly and the application works. However when I run everything in Docker containers (using Docker Compose) I find that the GraphQL API cannot connect to the NATS server and the microservice cannot connect with the MongoDB instance.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nats:
    container_name: nats
    image: nats
    ports:
      - 4222:4222
      - 6222:6222
      - 8222:8222
    networks:
      - services

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - services

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./apps/frontend/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  
  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    build:
      context: ./apps/gateway/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    environment:
      - NATS_URL="nats://nats:4222"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    networks:
      - services
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - mongo

  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    build:
      context: ./apps/user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    environment:
      - NATS_URL="nats://nats:4222"
      - MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017"
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    networks:
      - services
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - mongo

networks:
  services:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the code that attempts to send a message to the NATS server:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { map, Observable, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@Inject('NATS_CLIENT') private nats: ClientProxy) {}

  findAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.nats.send('users.get-users', {}).pipe(
      tap((result) => console.log('result', result)),
      map((user) => ({ name: user.name, email: user.email })),
      toArray(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the module that initialises the NATS client:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { UsersResolver } from './users.resolver';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'NATS_CLIENT',
        transport: Transport.NATS,
        options: {
          url: process.env.NATS_URL,
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [UsersService, UsersResolver],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

As you can see the connection string comes through as an environmental variable that was previously set in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

When I send a GraphQL request to trigger the send message I get the following error:

```
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL ::1:4222 - Local (:::0)
     at internalConnect (node:net:953:16)
     at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:465:18)
     at node:net:1044:9
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
   errno: -99,
   code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '::1',
   port: 4222
}
```

**Potential solutions tried:**

- I've tried different urls for the connection string including `nats://nats:4222`, `nats://localhost:4222`, `nats://127.0.0.1:4222`, `nats://0.0.0.0:4222`, `nats://host.docker.internal:4222`, etc. The end result of each of them is either the above error or a connection refused error.
- I've tried to ensure that the containers can communicate by running `docker exec [container1] ping [container2] -c2` where [container1]/[container2] are the respective container names. Doing this I always get a response.

It's been a long time since I've used Docker containers so I'd be interested if anybody has any ideas as this is driving me crazy!!

Comment: Could this just be a race condition (something trying to connect to the `nats` container before it's ready to accept requests)? If the `nats` container is up and running, can you access the service on port 4222 from inside the container? What if you `exec` into another one of your containers and try it?

Comment: @larsks I don't think so as I was trying to use the depends_on functionality from docker compose so that anything that utilises the NATS server would be created once the NATS server is established. Also there are communication issues from the user-service to MongoDB to so I'm leaning towards it being a network issue despite being able to ping between the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact issue you were with almost the same configuration. What fixed it for me was looking at the NATS documentation for Nest JS https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/nats. If you look at all the examples, they use the `servers` key to configure NATS instead of `url`. So try using the following inside your `UsersModule`:

```
ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'NATS_CLIENT',
        transport: Transport.NATS,
        options: {
          servers: [process.env.NATS_URL],
        },
      },
    ]),
```